# Visual Studio 2008 setup problem

Tags: visual-studio-2008

Visual Studio setup can't find **instpia11.exe**. What can I do to solve this?

Comment: Please provide more information. Are you installing from a DVD? What is the exact error message? ...

Answer (score 1):

IT should find it automatically. If it keeps happening, try a new CD. Maybe you got a bad disc.

Answer (score 0):

Just checked on my DVD ROM and instpia11.exe is located under *vs\wcu*. When it asks you again for the location of the file, **[*cd_path*]\vs**. Do not point to [*cd_path*]\vs\wcu